# Python Error: Application file not generated?

Tags: python, modeling, battery, openmodelica, simulate

I want to simulate a OpenModelica Model in Python with the help of OMPython. The following is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import OMPython
from OMPython import OMCSessionZMQ
from OMPython import ModelicaSystem
omc = OMCSessionZMQ()
mod = ModelicaSystem("Li_ionBattery.mo", "Li_ionBattery.TestBench.VaryingCurrent")
Li_simulation = mod.getSimulationOptions()
mod.setSimulationOptions(["stopTime=2000", "stepSize=50"])
variables_vary = mod.getQuantities()
Parameters_vary = mod.getParameters() 
continous_vary = mod.getContinuous() 
mod.setParameters(["nMC_Data.Q_nom=11", "nMC_Data.Rs=0.0003"])
mod.simulate()
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
Notification: Li_ionBattery requested package Modelica of version 3.2.2. Modelica 3.2.3 is used instead which states that it is fully compatible without conversion script needed.

Error: Class Li_ionBattery.TestBench.VaryingCurrent not found in scope <top>.
Error: Class Li_ionBattery.TestBench.VaryingCurrent not found in scope <TOP>.

stopTime !is not a simulation-option variable
Traceback (most recent call last):

 

raise Exception("Error: application file not generated yet")

Exception: Error: application file not generated yet
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is at line,

`mod = ModelicaSystem("Li_ionBattery.mo", "Li_ionBattery.TestBench.VaryingCurrent")`

as it reports,

`Error: Class Li_ionBattery.TestBench.VaryingCurrent not found in scope <top>.`

Make sure the class `Li_ionBattery.TestBench.VaryingCurrent` exists in `Li_ionBattery.mo`.

Comment: I checked and corrected it but now getting new error:                                          `AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'getchildren'` from  `File "/home/nupur/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/OMPython/__init__.py", line 974, in xmlparse
    ch = sv.getchildren()`

Comment: Which version of OMPython are you using?

Comment: I am using OMPython 3.3.0

Comment: the xml tree error is fixed in the OMPython master, but not available with the pip install, I recommend you to clone the OMPython from master and build it manually with the setup file "python setup.py install"